# How to config session lifetime lasts only 24 hours in CakePHP?

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am using CakePHP v4 for my application.

What I am going to do is to set session expires after 24 hours without inactivity.

A session should lasts 24 hours whether there some hours of inactivity or not.

Here is my config in the bootstrap.php file.

```
Configure::write('Session', [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    // 'timeout' => 1440,
    'cookieTimeout' => 1440, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
    'checkAgent' => false,
    'autoRegenerate' => false, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
]);
```

I should set `autoRegenerate` as false, right?

And `timeout` could be omitted, right?

A session should expire after 24 hours even inactivity.

So please let me know what is the correct config.

For now, the session expires if a browser is closed.

How to prevent session expire if a user close the browser?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** I am using session to keep my tokens.

```
$accessToken = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('accessToken');
```

I want to keep the accessToken 24 hours even though I closed my browser.

Answer (score 0):

By default PHP sets the session cookie to expire as soon as the browser is closed, regardless of the configured Session.timeout value. The cookie timeout is controlled by the session.cookie_lifetime ini value and can be configured using:

```
Configure::write('Session', [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => [
        // Invalidate the cookie after 30 minutes without visiting
        // any page on the site.
        'session.cookie_lifetime' => 1800
    ]
]);
```

See: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/sessions.html

Comment: Hello, thanks, it seems working now. Are you sure that a session would be expired after 1800 minutes?

Comment: Just setting `session.cookie_lifetime' => 1800` inside `ini` would solve my problem?

Comment: It doesn't expire even closing browser, but it expires after 20 minutes whether inside browser or outside browser. I don't expect that.

Comment: I use it like this. This is also suggested by the documentation! Accept the answer if it is satisfactory! Thanks.

Comment: No, your answer doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: OK. You said you were right. So I suggested accepting the answer. Success!